# Call named template for next sibling

Tags: xml, xslt, docbook

I have the following XML:

```
    <Text>
        <p id="258">Step.</p>
        <p id="1123">Step info.</p>
        <p id="258">Step.</p>
        <p id="1123">Step info.</p>
        <p id="258">Step.</p>
        <p id="1123">Step info:</p>
        <p id="1123">- Comment.</p>
        <p id="1123">- Comment.</p>
        <p id="1123">- Comment.</p>
    </Text>
```

I must turn it into a DocBook `<orderedlist>`:

```
<orderedlist>
        <listitem>
            <para>Step.</para>
            <para>
                <emphasis>Step info.</emphasis>
            </para>
        </listitem>
        <listitem>
            <para>Step.</para>
            <para>
                <emphasis>Step info.</emphasis>
            </para>
        </listitem>
        <listitem>
            <para>Step.</para>
            <para>
                <emphasis>Step info:</emphasis>
            </para>
            <para>
                <emphasis>- Comment:</emphasis>
            </para>
            <para>
                <emphasis>- Comment:</emphasis>
            </para>
            <para>
                <emphasis>- Comment:</emphasis>
            </para>
        </listitem>
    </orderedlist>
```

I first turn all `<p id="258">` elements into `<listitem><para>`:

```
<xsl:template match="AIT:p[@id='258'][1]">
    <orderedlist>
        <xsl:for-each select="../AIT:p[@id='258']">
            <xsl:call-template name="stepNoLine"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </orderedlist>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="stepNoLine">
    <listitem>
        <para>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|node()"/>
        </para>
    </listitem>
</xsl:template>
```

And I delete all non-first elements:

```
<xsl:template match="AIT:p[@id='258'][position() > 1]"/>
```

So far so good:

```
<orderedlist>
        <listitem>
            <para>Step.</para>
        </listitem>
        <listitem>
            <para>Step.</para>
        </listitem>
        <listitem>
            <para>Step.</para>
        </listitem>
    </orderedlist>
```

But now I do not know how to take care of `<p id="1123">` elements. All `<p id="1123">` between two `<p id="258">` must be siblings of the first `<p id="258">`, and children of `<listitem>`. Again:

```
    <listitem>
        <para>Step.</para>
        <para>
            <emphasis>Step info.</emphasis>
        </para>
    </listitem>
```

My puny attempt disgracefully fails in dishonor:

```
<xsl:template name="stepNoLine">
    <listitem>
        <para>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|node()"/>
        </para>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::AIT:p/@id='1123'">
            <xsl:call-template name="stepInfo"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </listitem>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="stepInfo">
    <para>
        <emphasis>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|node()"/>
        </emphasis>
    </para>
</xsl:template>
```

I get something like:

```
<orderedlist>
        <listitem>
            <para>Step.</para>
            <para>
                <emphasis>Step.</emphasis>
            </para>
        </listitem>
        <listitem>
            <para>Step.</para>
            <para>
                <emphasis>Step.</emphasis>
            </para>
        </listitem>
        <listitem>
            <para>Step.</para>
            <para>
                <emphasis>Step.</emphasis>
            </para>
        </listitem>
    </orderedlist>
```

In other words, each `<p id="258">` element is copied twice. I thought the `<xsl:if>` made the next sibling the current node, but I was evidently mistaken.

Other attempts (like using a `xsl:for-each` instead of `xsl:if`) failed in equally miserable ways.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: can you use XSLT-2.0?

Comment: I am using msxsl, but according to Microsoft that is XSLT 1.0 only. 
I see Saxon-HE 9.8 implements XSLt 3.0 - would that do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 you can use `for-each-group group-starting-with`:

```
<xsl:template match="Text">
    <orderedlist>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="p[@id = 258]">
            <listitem>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </listitem>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </orderedlist>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Text/p[@id = 258]">
    <para>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </para>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Text/*[not(self::p[@id = 258])]">
    <para>
        <emphasis>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </emphasis>
    </para>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thank you, the templates work as intended (although I am not sure I understand how they do it).

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays the right answer to almost any problem of this kind is going to be "use XSLT 2.0", but in environments where only XSLT 1.0 is available it's useful to be able to solve the problem in 1.0 as well.

Consider the following input, isomorphic to the example shown, but with different character data to make it easier to see what's happening:

```
 <Text>
   <p id="258">First step.</p>
   <p id="1123">Step info for step 1.</p>
   <p id="258">Step two.</p>
   <p id="1123">Step info for second step.</p>
   <p id="258">Step three.</p>
   <p id="1123">Step info for third step:</p>
   <p id="1123">- Comment on step 3.</p>
   <p id="1123">- Comment 2 on step 3.</p>
   <p id="1123">- Comment 3 on step 3.</p>
 </Text>
```

With this input, it's a little easier to see that (a) your draft stylesheet (assuming I have reconstructed it correctly from your description) does manage to get one `listItem` for each step (despite the slightly round-the-houses methods it uses to do so), but also that (b) it has no templates that match either the `Text` element or any `p` elements with `id="1123"`, which means that the default templates fire and we get a dump of their 1123 paragraphs' character data following the output from the template for the first 258 paragraph.

```
<orderedlist>
<listitem>
  <para>First step.</para>
  <para><emphasis>First step.</emphasis></para>
</listitem>
<listitem>
  <para>Step two.</para>
  <para><emphasis>Step two.</emphasis></para>
</listitem>
<listitem>
  <para>Step three.</para>
  <para><emphasis>Step three.</emphasis></para>
</listitem>
</orderedlist>
       Step info for step 1.

       Step info for second step.

       Step info for third step:
       - Comment on step 3.
       - Comment 2 on step 3.
       - Comment 3 on step 3.
```

The immediate problem in the code is that `stepNoLine` calls `stepinfo` without doing anything to change the context node, so the template application there processes the children of the 258 paragraph, not the following 1123 paragraphs.

The input you are processing has a great deal of information embedded in the sequence of elements; your pull-style stylesheet is ignoring that information and trying to recreate it out of nothing.  Your stylesheets will be simpler and will do better work if you let them be guided by the input, in what is usually known in XSLT programming as 'push' style.

In the following XSLT stylesheet, the template for `Text` calls xsl:apply-templates only for the children which should produce `listItem` elements, i.e. `p` elements with `id="258"`.  The 1123 paragraphs are not processed by that instruction.

The templates for the 258 paragraph elements, in turn, create all the content of the list item:  first the 258 paragraph, and then the sequence of all following `p` elements with `id="1123"`.  (We apply templates only to the first, but the first one takes care of the entire sequence.)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="Text">
    <xsl:element name="orderedList">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="p[@id='258']"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p[@id='258']">
    <xsl:element name="listitem">
      <xsl:element name="para">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]/self::p[@id='1123']"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p[@id='1123']">
    <xsl:element name="para">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]/self::p[@id='1123']"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

N.B. in the template for 258 elemetns we don't try to apply templates to all the appropriate sibling elements with `id="1123"`.  We could, and everything would be simpler, if we had a convenient way to say, in XPath 1.0, "all the immediately following `p` elements with `id="1123"` up to but not including the first `p` with `id="258"`, or the end of the parent element", and know with certainty that we had got it right.  It's simpler to say "take the immediately following sibling, if and only if it's a `p` with `id="1123"`, and than have the template for that element do the same thing.  When we reach a `p` with `id="1123"` whose immediately following sibling is not a `p` with `id="1123"`, or which has no following sibling, the recursion stops.

From the modified input, this produces as output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orderedList>
  <listitem>
    <para>First step.</para>
    <para>Step info for step 1.</para>
  </listitem>
  <listitem>
    <para>Step two.</para>
    <para>Step info for second step.</para>
  </listitem>
  <listitem>
    <para>Step three.</para>
    <para>Step info for third step:</para>
    <para>- Comment on step 3.</para>
    <para>- Comment 2 on step 3.</para>
    <para>- Comment 3 on step 3.</para>
  </listitem>
</orderedList>
```

which I believe is what is required.  (If you want to wrap the 1123 paragraphs' contents in `emph`, it should be easy to see where to do that.)

Comment: @CMS-McQ, what can I say, I bow to your mastery. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="Text">
    <xsl:element name="orderedlist">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="p[@id='258']"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@id='258'">
            <xsl:element name="listitem">
                <xsl:element name="para"><xsl:apply-templates /></xsl:element>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::p[1][@id = '1123']"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:element name="para">
                <xsl:element name="emphasis">
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::p[1][@id = '1123']"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: All, thank you for the replies. However, I realized my question was not very precise.

All elements from my example are meant to be children of the same <orderedlist>, but a <Text> element can also contain different lists or nested lists.

It is not always the case that <Text> becomes <orderedlist> as in all contributed <xsl:template match="Text">.
Sorry for the lack of clarity. All answers solve the problem stated, but I did not state the problem well.

I agree that XSLT 2.0 is not always the answer, but I am looking into <xsl:for-each-group> (h/t @Martin) with group-adjacent.